# Ruby on Rails: test best in place field with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, best-in-place

I want to simulate editing the best_in_place form to test it with cucumber

```
When /^I fill in change first name to "([^\"]*)"$/ do |value|
  bip_text(User, :first_name, value)
end

undefined method `bip_text' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x00000005665850> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file in features/support named `best_in_place_helpers.rb`, or whatever name appeals to you.

The contents should be:

```
include BestInPlace::TestHelpers
```